# How can I iterate multiple key from a dictionary in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, loops

I have given data from views to template in django. I want to iterate these multiple keys to build a html table.

views.py

```
data={'pacientes':p,'inicios':i,'finales':f,'enfermedad':enf} # p, i and f are lists
return render(request,'verEnf.html',data)
```

I want to do something like

index.html

```
 <table>
     {% for p, i, f in pacientes, inicios, finales %} # I know that this code is not work
        <tr>
            <td>{{ p.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ i }}</td>
            <td>{{ f }}</td>
        <tr>
     {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

p is an object from Pacientes

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    dni=models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)
    clave=models.CharField(max_length=16)
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
```

and i is a string's list as

```
('20-2-2014', '12-2-2014', ..., '11-5-2014')
```

Comment: Consider writing it out in Python before trying to translate it into a Django template.

Comment: So go and do it! What is the real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that each index of paciente, inicio and finales are related between them.

Just as Ignacio says, you can write some code in the view, before passing it to the template in order to solve your problem.
A possible solution could be packing the values in a list of tuples like this:

```
[
  (pacientes[0], inicios[0], finales[0]),
  (pacientes[1], inicios[1], finales[1]),
  ...
]
```

You can achieve this easily by using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function in your view:

```
pacientes_data = zip(p, i, f)
data={'pacientes_data':pacientes_data,'enfermedad':enf} # p, i and f are lists
return render(request,'verEnf.html',data)
```

And in your template:

```
<table>
     {% for p,i,f in pacientes_data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ p.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ i }}</td>
            <td>{{ f }}</td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a working solution for similar task:**

```html
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Model Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Device Count</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                  {% for all_model in all_models %}
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                    <td>{{ all_model.0 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ all_model.1 }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**In view.py**

```
    all_models = []
    all_models_names = [1,2,3,4]
    all_models_names_values = [1,2,3,4]
    all_models = zip(all_models_names,all_models_names_values)
return render(request, "sample.html",{'all_models':all_models})
```